# How to structure a program into classes

Tags: design, object-oriented, object-oriented-design

So after a while of working in programming field I still haven't figured it out how exactly should programs be structured, in a large set I mean. Which I think it's also because of working in an enterprise development.

Say that I want to write a program, a messenger for a LAN network. How do I really know what classes to make for this program? How to divide the program into smaller pieces and classes in the best and most efficient way? This is just an example. I don't mean specifically for this problem set, it's the general approach that I am wondering about.

EDIT: I have asked this question here because it exactly says in the help center:

> What topics can I ask about here?
>
> Programmers Stack Exchange is a Q&A site for professionals and
> students in software development and related fields who are interested
> in getting expert answers on conceptual questions about software
> development.
>
> If you have a question about...
>
> software requirements
>
> software architecture and design
>
> algorithm and data structure concepts

My question, according to my understanding, refers to the to the *software architecture and design*. It's not a specific coding question otherwise it would have been asked on Stackoverflow. It is a **conceptual question** which should be fit here. The comments and answers are referring to that there are a lot of books covering this topic. I'd accept even a book name for an answer if the book answers my question. If the answer does not fit into this form of Q&A, at least I could be pointed to the right direction. After all we're all here to learn something.

Comment: This is pretty much the definition of "too broad" to me.

Comment: "Your questions should be reasonably scoped..." ([help/dont-ask]) http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6490#6490

Comment: I cannot really see how would you make this question more specific. It's a valid question imho. I have not asked explain java to me (which I can see that it sounds so a bit) but what I really want to ask is how to break down a program into smaller pieces in the best way. I'd be glad to hear your comments and critics and help to ask in the right way if it's not. If it really does not fit the standards of this website, I remove it.

Comment: There are _many_, _large_ books written about how to structure programs. It's not a question we can answer well here.

Comment: @Erfan: The question is on topic here, but we can't really provide you with 200+ page answers. Much of your question fills entire textbooks on the topic of Object Oriented Analysis & Design.

Comment: Read [Head First Object Oriented Analysis and Design](http://www.headfirstlabs.com/books/hfooad/).  The reason you don't know what classes to make is because you've not done the prerequisite analysis. Perhaps the process should be called _analysis **then** design_

Comment: Thanks! I'll look into that. I also found [Object-Oriented Software Construction](http://www.amazon.com/Object-Oriented-Software-Construction-CD-ROM-Edition/dp/0136291554) which sounds fairly good in this topic by its reviews.

Answer (score 4):

By some definitions, a class is a type (or a structure) that provides implementation and interface (assuming it's not an abstract class) for some specific sub-set of a problem.

With that in mind we can say that most sensible way of organizing and naming class would be to divide them *logically*.

In your given example the classes could be:

```
Message
Session
Atendee
Status
Connection
... and so on
```

This is all strictly related to OOP: Object Oriented Programming - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming#Additional_features - if you take a look at the *Encapsulation enforces modularity* you could see that

> Encapsulation refers to the creation of self-contained modules that bind processing functions to the data. These user-defined data types are called "classes," and one instance of a class is an "object." For example, in a payroll system, a class could be Manager, and Pat and Jan could be two instances (two objects) of the Manager class. Encapsulation ensures good code modularity, which keeps routines separate and less prone to conflict with each other.

... which is more or less what I was trying to convey.